# Save par(mfrow) multipanel output as svg

Tags: r, svg, par

I'm using par(mfrow) to generate a multi-panel plot of three separate graph output objects. Sample code below represents a very simplified version of the objects I have.

How can I save these plots as a single object with ggsave? I've tried naming the par(mfrow) as an object and plotting it, but that doesn't seem to work.

Any advice on alternative ways of generating/saving a multi-panel plot is also welcome! Please let me know if I can clarify the question or example. Thanks!

```
par(mfrow = c(1,3), mar = c(10, 5, 5, 3), xpd = TRUE) 
hist(x = rnorm(100), col = "skyblue", main = "X")
hist(x = rnorm(50), col = "green", main = "Y")
legend("bottom", c("Blue", "Green", "Purple"),
        title = "Sample Data", horiz = TRUE, inset = c(0, -0.4),
        col = c("skyblue", "green", "purple"), pch = rep(15,2),
        bty = "n", pt.cex = 1.5, text.col = "black")
hist(x = rnorm(75), col = "purple", main = "Z")
```

Comment: (1) `ggsave` saves `ggplot2` graphics, this is all base R graphics, so `ggsave` will not work. (2) Start with `svg("path/to/file.svg")` *before* your call to `par(mfrow=..)`, then add `dev.off()` *after* your last `hist(.)`. You might prefer to specify dimensions in the call to `svg`, see its help documentation for more details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest using `svglite` over `svg` if you want to edit the graph using  Inkscape or a similar program since you will not be able to edit the text (change the text, font, or size) in a file produced by `svg`. Here is an example with a few edits to your original code:

```
library(svglite)
svglite("MyPlots.svg", width=8, height=6)
par(mfrow = c(1,3), mar = c(10, 5, 5, 3), xpd = TRUE, mgp=c(1.75, .75,  0)) 
hist(x = rnorm(100), col = "skyblue", main = "X")
hist(x = rnorm(50), col = "green", main = "Y")
legend("bottom", c("Blue", "Green", "Purple"),
        title = "Sample Data", horiz = TRUE, inset = c(0,  -0.2),
        col = c("skyblue", "green", "purple"), pch = rep(15,2),
        bty = "n", pt.cex = 1.5, text.col = "black")
hist(x = rnorm(75), col = "purple", main = "Z")
dev.off()
```

[image: Plot]

Comment: Thank you, @dcarlson! I appreciate knowing svglite will enable editing later on - very helpful!

Comment: @dcarlson, what's with the assertion that `svg` isn't post-render editable with something like Inkscape? I don't see much of a difference other than some different grouping of objects.

Comment: The text in `svg` is rendered as vectors so you cannot select a text box and edit the text inside it. If you look at the files each produces with a text editor, you will see the text labels in the file produced by `svglite`, but not in the file produced by `svg`. The down side is the the text in `svg` will automatically scale up or down as you enlarge or shrink the image, but not the one in `svglite`. There you have to select the text boxes and change the font size.

Comment: Here is a simple reproducible example. Run `plot.new(); text(.5, .5, "This is some text.")` with `svg` and `svglite` and compare the files with a text editor. The `svg` file is about 8 times larger.